# What is the difference between running jenkins with .war file and using installer?

Tags: jenkins

I would like to know what are the difference between using Jenkins on terminal with .war file vs using installer. And which is better?

Comment: No, this is about using the installer package vs. standalone WAR file.

Comment: Which is better is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the installer if you can. My main experience is with Linux but I’m pretty sure this applies to Windows as well:

- The installer will automatically pull in any dependencies that Jenkins needs in order to run
- You can easily upgrade Jenkins and its dependencies by installing a new version of the package
- It will set up Jenkins as a service that will restart automatically if the server reboots
- It provides a script to set parameters such as the JVM memory allocation and the port number that Jenkins runs on - if you use the JAR file you’d have to write a script yourself.